# Calling a normal function and/or ajax call based on user selection. I need ideas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I'm giving my user two buttons. I'll refer to them "Button 1" and "Button 2".

Button 1 does:

```
function button1 () {
    // push whatever data to Output
}
```

Button 2 does:

```
$.getJSON(x,function(){
    // my code for this is fine
    // push whatever data to Output
});
```

The user could pick either button. I don't want to run the ajax call at runtime, but when the user clicks Save at the end.

On save:

```
// checks to see which button is checked and chains the functions together 
// appropriately and sends all the data to Output as a string
```

It's a little more complicated / confusing than at first glance. Please give me your thoughts.

Comment: So just run `$.getJSON` when the user clicks "save" ?

Comment: so you have 3 buttons? button1, button2 and save?

Comment: Sounds like you want a radio choice, then on save, check which radio is selected?

Comment: @adeneo It's not that simple.

Comment: @steve correct.

Comment: @tymeJV Ignore the part about them being buttons - My buttons act like radios and that part works correctly.

Comment: How is it not that simple? When the user hits "save", check what radio is selected, or whatever you want really, then submit that data with an ajax call. If you have some output that is modified when the user selects something, send that.

Comment: You might want to provide a functional example, if it is more complicated than it appears.

Comment: If your buttons are simulating radios, then how are you indicating which radio/button is checked? If you're setting an attribute, like data-checked, it really is simple in saying something like `if(button1.data('checked')) { /* run button1 code */ } else { /* run button2 ajax */ } ` in your save function...